# How to import Social framework only for iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

How to import Social framework only for iOS 6? I want to disable the Social Framework for other iOS versions. Currently I am trying this and I also tried to change the FrameWork to optional, But not running on iOS 5.1 simulator.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0)
        {
          #import <Social/Social.h>   
        }
```

Please tell how to check and run for both iOS 5 and iOS 6. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly: don't query the OS version for guessing what is supported, check if a particular feature is actually available instead of using it based on assumptions.

That said, recent versions of iOS and the toolchain support weak linking. Just check for the class you're intending to use is not `Nil` (method #1). You can also use the Objective-C runtime for this (method #2):

```
// method #1 - weak linking
if ([SLRequest class] != Nil) {
    // Social.framework is available
}

// method #2 - querying the runtime
if (NSClassFromString(@"SLRequest") != Nil) {
    // Social.framework is available
}
```

For weak linkage to take effect, the frameworks you intend to use like this shall be added as "optional" instead of as "required". If you don't use Xcode or an IDE but only a command line toolchain, weak linkage can be enforced by passing

```
-flat_namespace -undefined dynamic_lookup
```

to the linker.

Comment: @Macmade Yes, small things that come with experience :) You should know `Nil` is for classes even if you never use it... Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the Social.framework must be added to the target as an optional (and not required) framework in addition to the mentioned runtime checks.

Comment: Hope you guys see this comment, i see how that would work in this scenario, how would this work on the importing and adding Delegates to your class. Avoiding the replies below for importing..or at least trying. I have the framework set to 'Optional' but can i #import from it without causing any issues for the the non-desired case, i.e. ios4 only software.

Comment: @H2CO3 Which of these method is better to use (i.e. what are the pros and cons of one vs the other)?

Comment: @keale Not much difference. Use whichever one you like better.

Answer (score 2):

```
#import <Avaibility.h>

#if defined(__IPHONE_6_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_6_0
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#elif defined(__IPHONE_5.0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_5_0
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#else
#error Your SDK is too old ! Need at least 5.0.
#endif
```

Comment: This is not a valid approach. Do not do this. This is a compile time check, not a runtime check.