# how to check if condition in preprocessor macro?

Tags: iphone, ios, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to import Social framework only for iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002304/how-to-import-social-framework-only-for-ios-6)

Need of check if condition in preprocessor macro.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)

/*
 *  Usage
 */



if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
{
#import <Social/SLServiceTypes.h>
#import <Social/SLRequest.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Social/SocialDefines.h>
}
```

Comment: Also, don't test for the iOS version/device type and don't guess, check for features.

Answer (score 1):

You can't import files at run time. `imports` works at compile time.
As the above macro is using methods that will calculate values at run time so I don't think whatever you are trying to achieve is possible

Answer (score 1):

As noted, `#import` is a compile-time directive -- all preprocessor directives (stuff that starts with `#`) are. So what you appear to be trying to do here won't work the way you expect it to.

So long as you're only building with the latest SDK, you don't need to conditionally `#import` headers -- the newest headers will be available to you regardless of what target iOS version you're building for.

If your code needs to be build under different SDK versions -- e.g. if you have a teammate whose machine can't run the latest Xcode, that's a time for conditional imports. But since this is a compile-time thing, you need a compile-time check against your SDK version, not a run-time check. Use something like:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_6_0
// building with iOS 6 SDK, safe to import Social framework
#endif
```

Again, though, you only need to do something like that if you expect your code to be *built* using an older SDK.

If you want your app to *run* on older iOS versions but want to conditionally use new iOS features, that's when you need runtime checks. You'll also want to make use of [weak linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW6). Even then, however, Apple recommends you avoid checking version numbers -- it's better to check for the specific functionality you need. For example, if you want to use the Social framework, weak link the entire framework [(i.e. make it Optional)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1), then check for the existence of the class you want before using it:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController class] {
    SLComposeViewController *vc = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    // ...
}
```

Why avoid version number checks? Well, suppose you checked for an iOS version greater than 5.1 before trying to use Social framework APIs... then suppose Apple releases another 5.1.x update to fix a security hole. Now, your app thinks it's on a version that has the Social framework, tries to use it, crashes, and gets you bad reviews on the App Store. What if you check for 6.0... then Apple might change their mind about shafting original-iPad owners and release a 5.x update that at least lets us have *some* of the iOS6 features, including Social? Now your app doesn't crash, but it also doesn't let your users have the new iOS features -- again with the one-star reviews.

Answer (score 0):

The structure is pretty much as simple as: `#IF ... #ENDIF`

Here are some useful links:
[First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyscbeay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), 
[Second](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html), 
[Third](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)