# How to set compile time flags to include specific framework at runtime

Tags: objective-c, macos

Our application is supported from Mac OS X 10.5 and we are including a feature which has support from Mac OS X 10.7 and above.

How can I make a common application where in the customers on 10.5 and 10.6 doesn't get that feature and 10.7 and above get that feature.

What should be the conditional flag I should use in the code so that framework shouldn't be loaded once the application run on 10.6 and below?

Comment: Linker flags: `-ObjC -flat_namespace -undefined dynamic_lookup`, and in your code, check if `[ClassYouWantToUse class] != Nil`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import Social framework only for iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002304/how-to-import-social-framework-only-for-ios-6)